# What kind of rails route is this? get '/(@:version)' => 'interfaces#home'

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I just started a new project and I found a route in the rails router I've never seen before and I'm having a hard time identifying it.

What is the `(@:version)` of this route? it looks like its being used dynamically as it shows up many times in this project's router.

`get '/(@:version)' => 'interfaces#home', as: 'home'`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That is a **regex match** on the route and will assign anything after the `@` sign to the variable `version` in your `interfaces_controller#home`

To hit the route, visit `/@foobarbaz` and the params hash will have a key of `:version` set to `foobarbaz`

To further drive home, you could do something like this in the routes

```
get '/(99:version)' => 'application#index', as: 'home'
```

and hit `/99foobarbaz` and it will set the same params key of `:version` with value of `foobarbaz`

Comment: I didn't realize the () meant it was optional, the @ was a red herring